# How to share .txt file in by opening the email app and attaching the file to a compose mail in flutter windows?

Tags: flutter, email, text-files, share, flutter-windows

I want my flutter windows app to send a text file by opening the default mail app in my windows machine and then attaching the file. I have been using URL launcher but I can't seem to find how to attach a file when opening the mail app I could only change the subject and email to address.

Comment: Please post some code and specify more details

Comment: I only need a void that could open mail and atach a file from a specific path